# how to merge cells in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

how to merge cells in jTable to be like this table

[image]

Comment: google: `java jtable colspan` should give you few nice answers like http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm

Comment: actually i saw that answer but unfortunately it was hard to understand for me .
i wonder if there's a solutions more simple